# what is gettimeofday() equivalent in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gettimeofday

Probably duplicate, but What is `gettimeofday()` equivalent in c++11 ?

I am trying to get 64 bit `timestamp` with microseconds, similar to Java / Python.

Comment: If you think it's "probably duplicate", why did you not spend time instead finding that duplicate?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).

**UPDATE**

You can check the necessary minimal precision by this static assert:

```
static_assert (std::ratio_less_equal<std::chrono::system_clock::duration::period,
    std::ratio<1,100> >::value, "");
```

Comment: Are we sure it is *always* offering a microsecond resolution? Can't a C++11 compliant implementation only give a decisecond-accurate system clock?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - decisecond good for me. I don't think Java do microseconds.

Comment: @Nick I've no idea what Java's resolution is but you seemed to think Java measures in microseconds when you posted your question: _trying to get 64 bit timestamp with microseconds, similar to Java / Python._

Comment: there is also a `high_resolution_clock` which might or might not be the same as `system_clock`

Answer (score 2):

To get the highest resolution supported by your system, use [`std::high_resolution_clock::now`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock). The high-resolution clock may be an alias for `std::chrono::system_clock`.